# How do I automatically format all numbers based on the current locale in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am aware of

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
```

But I want all the numbers shown in my app to be formatted according to the locale, thus I don't think it will be a good way to format them one by one using the above method.

So is there some global setting/variable/configuration that I have to change in order to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Locale-aware formatting requires more than just translating e.g. month names from one language to another. In Java that's handled by separate classes apart from the ones that actually hold the values, e.g. `NumberFormat`, `DateFormat`. So there's no way around using them like you already do.

What you could try is to create some wrappers or convenience methods (like `formatDate(Date)`) to simplify things for you. Also put format strings into Android Resources (`res/values`).